# Nether portal block correspondence

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to make a large (6x7) nether portal that is the same size in both dimensions. I would like to make each portal block link to the corresponding block because of some of the peculiarities of my design. (Long story short, it's a divided hallway.)

Here's the layout I have now: (O: Obsidian, P: Portal block)

```
OOOOOOOOO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OPPPPPPPO
OOOOOOOOO
```

Currently, no matter which portal block I enter from, I appear at the same one each time. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: There was a way in the past at least, SimplySarc made a video about a portal where jumping right before getting teleported brought you to a different room. I don't know if that still works. And very likely not for 42 blocks. Have you looked at the [portal linking tutorial](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Nether_portals) yet?

Comment: Oh, you're taking about MCPE. There it could be totally different. You used the Java Edition tag as well, that's why I'm here. :D

Comment: *"I always appear at the same one."* Do you mean the same block you entered on, or the same block as every other time (like the left corner)?

Comment: Same block each time.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Overworld coordinates correspond to Nether coordinates in 8:1 proportions, there's no way to achieve what you want - an 8x8 square in the Overworld corresponds to a single block in the Nether.